# Get data of the previous session issue - Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email, data

I passed some data in session in `success.phtml` to get it in `order_new.phtml` **email template**, all goes well except the value that i get is that of the previous session !. I think the email it sends before I retrieve the data. **Exemple:** instead to get 104, i get 103.

Have you an idea how to handle this case.

**success.phtml:**

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('my-code', $code); ?>
```

**code.phtml**

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('my-code'); ?>
```

**order_new.html:**

```
<td>{{block type="core/template" area="frontend" template="email/code.phtml"}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use magento `registery` instead of session

```
Mage::register('name-of-registry-key', $your-data);//set data

$var = Mage::registry('name-of-registry-key');//get data

Mage::unregister('name-of-registry-key');//unset data
```

Comment: it doesn't work @Murtuza Zabuawala, i can't registry the data in `code.phtml` when i Mage::log the registry in the same file `success.phtml` i get it but not in the other.

Comment: i find that it's normal that the registry not work because i retrieve my data from another page(is not persisted), this is why i used `getData` (is persisted)